# Problem with hyphens in listings

Tags: listings

The problem is that in the inline listing "ABC-ABC" the hyphen disappears. It works if I remove the literate=... parameter but I need it because I want to wrap around long inline code by specifying manual hyphenation markers with "-". How can I solve this problem?

Another weird thing is that inline listing only works with \newcommand as the second part in the example shows. Is this a bug?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{Inline}
{
    literate={\-}{}{0\discretionary{-}{}{}}
}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\lstinline[style=Inline]{#1}}

\begin{document}
\code{ABC-ABC}\\
\code{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABC\-ABC}\\[1cm]
Bug in listings???\\
\code{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABC\-ABC}\\
\lstinline[style=Inline]{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABC\-ABC}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should avoid capturing the argument in `\code`. Rather try: `\newcommand{\code}{\lstinline[style=Inline]}`

Comment: Then I get ...AAAAABC\ABC instead of ...AAAAABCABC or ...AAAAABC-<new line>ABC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two issues:

- `\-` is the same as `-` in `literate`, if you want to have a backslash in front of the hyphen, then the backslash needs to be escaped by a backslash. The hyphen does not need to be escaped by a backslash: `\\-` catches the backslash and the hyphen.

  From the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf):

  > 4.1 How to read the reference
  >   ...
  >    5. If you want to enter one of the special characters `{}#%\`, this character must
  >     be escaped with a backslash. This means that you must write `\}` for the
  >     single character ‘right brace’—but of course not for
  >     the closing paramater
  >     character.
- Package `listings` reads the code with changed catcodes. If the code for `\lstinline` is already read as argument, the argument is tokenized and catcode changes do not have an effect, see Werner's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168527/problem-with-hyphens-in-listings#comment387571_168527):

  ```
  \newcommand*{\code}{\lstinline[style=Inline]}
  ```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{Inline}
{
    literate={\\-}{}{0\discretionary{-}{}{}}
}
\newcommand{\code}{\lstinline[style=Inline]}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\code{ABC-ABC}\\
\code{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABC\-ABC}\\
\code{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABC\-ABC}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]