# Can't get listings to behave at line endings despite use of breaklines parameter

Tags: listings, margins, geometry, page

I'm having trouble with getting listings to behave at line endings and respect the page margins. Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{courier}
\lstset{
  language=[Visual]Basic,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  breaklines=true,
  numberstyle=\small\ttfamily,
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
  Sub TEstThatLongVariableNamesDontBreakUpProperlyWithinTheLstListingEnvironmentCheckitOutForYourselfIsntThatWeird()
    Debug.Print("hello world")
  End Sub
\end{lstlisting}

\blindtext

Here is a very long variable name which overflows the line and needs to not do that see what I mean \lstinline!Supercalifrcexpialidocious!

\end{document}
```

Here's what the result looks like:

[image]
Neither the `lstinline` command nor the `lstlsting` are respecting the page margins despite use of the `breaklines` option in `lstset`.

I need for the verbatim lines to break up properly and automatically at the page margins. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

With long words you have to insert an hyphenation point to suggest a break place.

Later, with the `literate` keyword, each `\-` is replaced by the red `\hookrightarrow`.

`breaklines=true` activates the automatic line breaking of long **lines of code**. For example if   `breakatwhitespace=true` allows  to insert a line break only at a  white space.

**Note**
For `inline` listing, it is possible to add as many `\-` as you like (see the answer), to tell TeX where a proper line break could occur. Tex will make (mostly) a good choice.

That way changing the text of the document should not be a big problem. In the final version, like all the overflow boxes,  they will need  to be  visually checked.

This is normal procedure with long proper names, foreign words, etc. when the hyphenation tables do not have a proper place to hyphenate.

The  difference between the two styles is where the red arrow appears. For inline it is better to have it before the line break.

Related answers

[hyphens in listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168532/161015)

[listings line wrapping](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116572/161015)

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[showframe,margin=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{courier}

%   https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168532/161015
%   https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116572/161015   
\lstdefinestyle{display}% displayed listings
{
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
numberstyle=\small\ttfamily,
language=[Visual]Basic,
columns=fullflexible,
xleftmargin=30pt,
breaklines=true,
breakatwhitespace=true,
breakindent=30pt,
keywordstyle=\color{blue},
literate={\\-}{}{0\discretionary{}{\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space}}{}}  %arrow in the new line
    }

\lstdefinestyle{inline}
{%
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,%
literate={\\-}{}{0\discretionary{\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space}}{}{}}  % arrow before line break
}

\begin{document}    

\begin{lstlisting}[style=display]
Sub
Public UserID As Integer  TEstThatLongVariableNamesDontBreakUp\-ProperlyWithin\-TheLstListingEnvironment\-CheckitOutForYourselfIsnt\-ThatWeird() 
Debug.Print("hello world")
End Sub
\end{lstlisting}

\blindtext
    
Here is a very long variable name which overflows the line and needs to not do that see what I mean
{\color{green!40!black}
 \lstinline[style=inline]!Asanydedicatedreadercanclearly\-seeour\-apriori\-conceptsarewhatfirst\-giverisetthe\-Categories\-Hume\-tell\-sus\-that\-our\-ideasarejust\-asnecessary\-asontheother\-hand\-natural\-causes!}
            
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get LaTeX to automatically detect where the line break *should* occur? This is particularly important for `lstinline` because the position where the line breaks will have to change as I add or delete text in my document...

Comment: @user32882 Please see the updated answer and the Note.

Comment: I don't know if adding a ton of hyphenations inside the long variable names is actually a good solution. I found another post recommending the use of `\sloppy` for `\lstinline` elements and I think this might work better....

Comment: @user32882  With meaningful variable names, 3 or 4 `\ -` should be sufficient. You don't want TeX to cut the name in an arbitrary place and add a `-` which might or might not be part of the name.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\lstset{
  language=[Visual]Basic,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  breaklines=true,
  numberstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  literate={T}{T}{1},%here the main feature, just a small hack you know, but it can  help You, I hope
}

%\lstinputlisting{code/test.py}
\begin{lstlisting}
  Sub TEstThatLongVariableNamesDontBreakUpProperlyWithinTheLstListingEnvironmentCheckitOutForYourselfIsntThatWeird()
    Debug.Print("hello world")
  End Sub
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```